# How to reference Lombok generated methods in Javadocs?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, lombok

I am currently having issues with writing my javadocs and I keep getting `Tag @link: can't find getProjected() in XXXX` when this is a getter generated by Lombok.

My javadoc is `@return the XXX {@link #getProjected()}`.

Is there anyway of actually referencing these methods as they are created at compilation?

(I am using Eclipse IDE)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Lombok plugin for Eclipse.

This [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide#eclipse) describes the installation process in full, but the essence is:

1. Download the latest lombok jar
2. At a command prompt run `java -jar lombok-x.x.x.jar` which launches the installer UI
3. Locate the Eclipse installation
4. Click <kbd>Install / Update</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already have it installed on Eclipse but my issue is that I cant reference the generated methods. I have them 'hidden', but they do exist and are generated at compile time.